# Why is "woman" in "the woman teacher" an adjunct while "literature" in "the literature teacher" a complement?

Tags: syntax, english, historical-linguistics, grammar

Is it because we cannot say "teacher of woman" but we can say "teacher of literature"?

Comment: I'd probably call them both adjuncts. Can you tell us more about who categorises them as you describe?

Comment: Who says they are?

Comment: You're on the right lines, though I wouldn't call either of them adjuncts -- that term is best reserved for modifiers (or supplements) in clause structure, not noun phrase structure. In "the woman teacher", "woman" ascribes the property of being a woman to the teacher and hence is a modifier. In "the literature teacher", "literature" doesn't modify "teacher" but is a complement where the meaning is 'a teacher of literature'.

Comment: Note that "woman teacher", without stress specified, is ambiguous.  A "woman TEAcher" is a teacher who is a woman.  A "WOman teacher: is one who teaches women.  Only the latter has the stress typical of compounds.